# python `subprocess.run()` returning unexpected empty stdout in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner, python, testing

I'm attempting to have my python blackbox test suite run through gitlab-ci. When running the test through `pipenv run pytest` on my personal machine everything executes correctly, but when running on the docker image with the same versions my call to `subprocess.run(command, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)` returns a CompletedProcess with an unexpected empty stdout and stderr values. No other errors show up other than the tests failing from the empty output. Is there some requirement that I'm missing for gathering output from subprocesses on the ci-runner? I imagine if the subprocess itself failed I should at least be getting something in stderr or the return code should be non-zero, but it that isn't the case.

The failure in question:

```
    def test_help():
        """test running <command>'s `help` option, and the command on various subcommands"""
        out = run_command_subprocess(None, "-h")
        assert out.stderr == ""
>       assert out.stdout.startswith("usage: <command>")
E       AssertionError: assert False
E        +  where False = ('usage: <command>')
E        +    where  = ''.startswith
E        +      where '' = CompletedProcess(args=['<path_to_python>', '<command>', '-h'], returncode=0, stdout='', stderr='').stdout
```